# Difference between dimension and channel

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an image stored as a numpy array:

```
image = np.array([
    [[ 11,  12],
     [ 13,  14],
     [ 15,  16]],
    [[ 21,  22],
     [ 23,  24],
     [ 25,  26]],
    [[ 31,  32],
     [ 33,  34],
     [ 35,  36]]])
```

I print the shape and dimensions:

```
>>> print('image shape', image.shape, 'image dimensions', image.ndim)
image shape (3, 3, 2) image dimensions 3
```

I understand that the matrix is 3 of Height, 3 of Width and 2 of color channel(?)

But.... if the dimension of the matrix is 3 .. What is the difference between dimension and color channel?

Comment: Dimension is the number of elements in shape. A (3,) array has dimension 1. (3,3) had dimension 2; (3,3,3) had dimension 3, etc.

Comment: In your particular case, you choose to interpret axis 0, which has size 3, as the different channels of your image. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: Okay, I understand intuitively that are the dimensions, but in wich cases we use more than 3 dimensions?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer momentarily. Working on it right now.

Comment: All done. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherent properties of an array are `shape` and `ndim`. Shape is the size of an array in each dimension. `image.ndim` is just a shortcut for `len(image.shape)`. Another related quantity is `image.size`, which is `np.prod(image.shape)`. In numpy, dimensions are called "axes", and start with zero. So the first index in an array corresponds to axis 0, the second to axis 1, etc.

Which dimension is "channel" is entirely up to interpretation. Generally, it will be the last dimension, but I have seen it as the first as well. Even more generally, dimensions generally correspond to some useful coordinates in your array. Remember that not all arrays are images. Data can be totally arbitrary, and will be based on your use-case.

Your example is slightly confusing because `image.ndim == image.shape[0] == image.shape[1]`. Here is an example of an array containing *multiple* RGB images, all of the same size:

```
images = np.random.randint(255, size=(5, 7, 7, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

We can interpret axis 0 as the index of the image, axis 1 as the width, axis 2 as the height, and axis 3 as the color channel. In that case, we have five images of size 7x7, with three color channels each. If the channels are R, G, B, then `images[3, 0, 0, 2]` is the blue component of the upper-left pixel in the fourth image.

Comment: thank you for the very well developed answer, but... just for curiosity, if I say :                                   
images = np.random.randint(255, size=(5, 7, 7, 3, 2, 1)) .                                                 what would  represent  the axis -2 and -1 ? what if I add more axis?

Comment: @LuisAnaya. What I'm trying to get across is that Numpy arrays are used to store(real) data. You can structure the array in any way you want, that makes sense, in the real world. Contrived examples have little meaning except as a reflection of reality. If you give me an array with more dimensions, it's you who has to say what those dimensions are, not me :)

Comment: aaaaah ok, perfect, finally yes, I was a little confused with this topic, now I understand it better, thank you very much for your effort